# Ruta home no encontrada (Error 404)

Tags: laravel

Estoy teniendo el problema de que me da el error 404 al intentar acceder a la ruta de home.

Sin embargo tengo la ruta definida y si la consulto con un route list la puedo ver.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto solo me pasa en producción. En el entorno de desarrollo funciona bien y ya ejecute los comandos para  limpiar el cache de las rutas.

En mi codigo la tengo definida de esta forma:

```
Route::get('/home', 'homeClienteController@index')->name('home_cliente.index')->middleware('can:home.cliente');
```

Comment: Todas las rutas funcionan menos esa.

Comment: @JuanRivera si, he probado muchas cosas. Ahora mismo me acabo de dar cuenta que el controlador es el problema.